Saving $! (process ID of last background command) as an array element
I can't understand the way zsh 5.9 behaves when assigning $! to an array:
unset a b c

sleep 3 &

a=$!
b[1]=$!
c[1]=${!}

typeset -p a b c

output:
typeset a=21391
typeset -a b=( '$!' )
typeset -a c=( 21391 )

Getting b=( '$!' ) doesn't feel right... Is it a feature? A regression?

On Linux I get b=( 20769 ) with zsh 5.0.2 and b=( '$!' ) with zsh 5.5.1.

b[1]="$!" works as expected, too. It's just the bare case. Weird.

I'd report it as a bug

with b[1]="$!" I get an unmatched " using zsh 5.9. I have to add a backslash for the quotes to work: b[1]="$\!"... you're right, it feels like a bug

I reported the bug to zsh-workers@zsh.org

I was testing with 5.9; didn't get the unmatched error.... I bet it has something to do with history expansion, since ! is used for that.

I can reproduce it with zsh 5.8.1 on MacOS.

The problem's been fixed in commit 5977d3c

But IMHO it's best not to rely on arr[1]=$! anymore and use the following workaround to be portable across zsh versions:
arr[1]=${!}

